# How can I receive data from a machine to my local ASP.NET Core application using WebSocket?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tcp

I have an application in asp.net core 5. And I want to receive data from a machine in my application. There are several examples over the internet about the matter. But I might get confused on these implementations. I want just machine can send data to my application only and application only the responsible to receive data thought the local TCP/IP connection.
Please give me some suggestion by providing examples or relevant blogs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The asp.net core is built with the http based application. If you are using the asp.net core web application, it will be based on the http.sys. If don't want just TCP/IP connection, you should write the application by yourself. Like this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-6.0) shows.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Thank for your response. I have already written a asp.net core application that is listening to a port 127.0.0.1:1020 which is a windows form application. When I run it using VS then Windows form application can send message to core application. When I published the core app on the IIS then the Windows form cannot send message to my hosted asp.net core application. It says no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. How do I solve it?